# EF6, Slow Azure Sql Writes, TransactionHandler

Tags: performance, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am posting this in case anyone else runs into the same problem.   We implemented the EF6 TransactionHandler which is suppose to help transient errors on Sql Azure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630221(v=vs.113).aspx

We didn't realize the table does not get cleaned.    Eventually the __transactionHistory table had thousands of records.   Every time we wrote to SQL, because of this mechanism, it caused horrible 5-10 second delays.

The fix, we removed it.   The implementation from MS should have auto cleaned that table.   Ours did not.

Ef6 Azure Sql slow writes

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't really a question, I just wanted to post something about it in case others search for EF6 Azure Sql Performance.